# Função Assíncrona em C# Web

Tags: c#

Estou realizando uma pagina web que faz uma pesquisa no banco de dados e utilizando em apenas uma maquina fica tudo normal, porem, quando a pesquisa é utilizada mais de uma vez, como por exemplo, em duas maquinas diferentes, a pesquisa da erro.

Testei outros modos de pesquisa, mas também da erro, queria saber se existe alguma forma de deixar essa pesquisa assíncrona com o modo `async/await` ou algo do tipo, segue a pesquisa e o erro:

```
public static FbDataAdapter GetDataAdapter(string query)
{
    FbConnection myConn = ConnectionFB.GetInstance().GetConnectionFb();

    myConn.Close();
    myConn.Open();
    FbDataAdapter da;
    try
    {
        da = new FbDataAdapter(new FbCommand(query, myConn));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("Impossível criar tabela a partir de uma instrução SQL.",
           ex.InnerException);
    }
    return da;
}
```

---

```
public static DataSet GetData(string query)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet("dsPadrao");
    try
    {
        FbConnection.ClearAllPools();
        FbDataAdapter da = new FbDataAdapter(new FbCommand(query, myConn));
        da.Fill(ds);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("Impossível criar dataset a partir de uma instrução SQL.", ex);
    }
    return ds;
}
```

O erro é esse:

> [image: Erro]

o banco de dados que estou utilizando é `Firebird`, mas acho que isso não seja o algo relevante, já que pesquisando apenas uma vez, a pesquisa não apresenta erro.

Comment: Sua pergunta está tanto confusa... O erro acontece quando você repete a pesquisa? O que outras máquinas tem a ver com a questão? Você já debugou o seu código?

Comment: por que você está matando todo o pool no `GetData()`

Comment: faz um bloco using instanciando uma nova conexão e encerre-a no final

Comment: O seu código já é estranho porque fecha e abre conexão, sem você verificar se realmente esta aberta, vejo problemas nisso, o erro anexado com imagem na sua pergunta não diz realmente, você tem que dizer onde acontece realmente esse erro em qual linha e qual momento faz tudo isso, é um erro local

Comment: além de q não vi o q tem a ver um código com o outro

Comment: Bom, vou tentar resumir aqui, estou desenvolvendo um relatório web. Aparentemente está dando conflito nas funções de pesquisa. Como esse relatório pode ser usado em mais de um local, como em dois pcs diferentes, ele quebra quando tento gerar dois relatórios ao msm tempo, mesmo que com informações diferentes. Queria saber se existe alguma forma de deixar essas funções de uma forma assíncrona. Se precisar, posto todas as formas de pesquisa que ja utilizei, e como foi relatado que essas que postei estão incorretas, como eu posso corrigi-las?

Answer (score 1):

Bruno pela mensagem de erro tudo indica que seja a consulta (query). Se ainda precisar de ajuda posta a consulta.

Comment: Anderson, o problema em si é conflito na utilização da função da pesquisa. Quando eu pesquiso e espero que seja gerado, o relatório sai normal. Quando eu gero ele uma vez e antes de ser gerado, eu pesquiso outra vez(sendo em outra maquina ou na mesma), ele apresenta o erro.

Comment: Entendi @BrunoMiqueas valeuu pelo retorno.